# ¿Qué tipo de formato de fecha es este 2022-04-24T11%3A09%3A32?

Tags: date

Me han pasado un ejemplo de llamada a una api con este fomato de fecha:
`endDate=2022-04-24T11%3A09%3A32`
Y no se que significan la A el %.
Tampoco esto 100% de a que corresponden minutos segundos etc...
Ni si los tengo que recontruir con una o dos cifras, en formato de 12 o de 14...
A alguien le resulta familiar este formato.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

Comment: vulgarmente conocido como Zulu

Comment: Pues ponmelo como respuesta y cerramos esto :D.

Comment: Esta pregunta no trata sobre programación dentro del alcance definido en el [help]

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro ¿Por qué no es de programacion?
Estoy programando en php. una añi me manda ese formato, y si no lo se no puedo seguir.

Comment: @E-Rick Saber el nombre de un formato o tecnología no es programación. Por ejemplo, si una persona pone el código con un bucle `for` y pregunta "¿Qué tipo de bucle es éste?", la pregunta puede estar relacionada con la programación, pero no es programación en sí. La pregunta fue cerrada, que significa que no puede recibir más respuestas (ya hay una aceptada) pero puede seguir recibiendo votos y comentarios.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Conocido comunmente como date time Zulu

Aqui te paso un link
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

Comment: Me gustaría saber por que se no considera una respuesta